# OAuth Unauthorized error without src directory NextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js, oauth, auth0

I am using auth0-js library for auth in nextjs. I have setup social logins, they work when the app router is inside of the src directory but when there's no src directory and app router is in the root of the project, the social login gives unauthorized(401) error during the callback.
Callback Url : http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback
My folder structure without src directory :

```
└── root/
    ├── app/
    │   └── (root)/
    │       └── (routes)/
    │           ├── api/
    │           │   └── auth/
    │           │       └── login/
    │           │           └── page.tsx
    │           ├── home/
    │           │   └── page.tsx
    │           ├── layout.tsx
    │           └── globals.css
    ├── public
    ├── components
    ├── lib
    ├── context/
    │   └── app-context.tsx
    └── node_modules
```

My login function, I just made a context and I am handling login from this

```
function handleLogin(provider: string) {
    webAuth.authorize({
        connection: provider
    });
}
```

I want to know what am I missing, do i need to add a path somewhere?

Tried deleting .next files and restarting, checked all the callback and redirect urls, but nothing seems to be working.